# Good places / ways for a low level player to collect ingots (or rings) in Anarchy Online

Tags: anarchy-online

I'm trying to make some money making jewelery but creations don't cover the production costs because I only have access to QL 1 ingots/rings.

Where / How can I obtain ingots/rings and jems of better QLs as a low level player (~ lvl 20)?

I've seen them occasionally drop from mission mobs but I'd rather not trust in fate if there's a better way.

Comment: This question could easily be expanded to "Is there an AO loot database site of note?" as my first instinct was to go to Thottbot...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where to get them reliably, but I seem to remember a good place for looting in general at that level is the Subway. I played as an engineer down there some time ago, and managed to make some filigree rings from the things I found.

Looking at the boss drops there's a couple of rare rings there, but that may or may not be a good indicator.